# Javascript forms Value disappear

Tags: javascript, html, dom

First the code:

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
     <script>
        function calc_form(first, second) {
            x = document.getElementById("calc");
            first = document.forms["calc"].elements["first"].value;
            second = document.forms["calc"].elements["second"].value;
            third =  first*second;
            document.forms["calc"].elements["result"].value = third;
            document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = third;
        }
    </script>
<form name = "calc">
    <input type = "text" name="first">
    <input type="text" name="second">
    <input type="submit" onclick = "calc_form()"><br>
    <input type="text" id="result">
</form>
<p id="result1"></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

I know that this is a useless and very poor code but I want to know that why does the values that I enter in the input box disappear right after I click the "Submit" button.

Similarly, the result in the third input box appears only for a moment and then disappears. Why is this happening?

Comment: They dissapear because the form is submitted, and the page reloads

Comment: when you click on the submit button the page reloads. Thats why the values disappear.

Comment: Change type="submit" to type="button"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When one click on html submit button, the form values are collected and server request is generated. Depending on request type defined (POST or GET), the data are sent to the server in URL or form format. After request the page is refreshed because the client html code is rendered again.

You can build the logic reading the values after server side response received results to client. However, I guess you need in your code to to prevent sending data to the server side each time you click on the button and to make calculations on the client only. There're two ways you could do that:

1. change the type of the button from "submit" to "button".
2. in the oncick event as well as at the end of the function "return false". It prevents from the submit action and sending submit request to server.

   <input type="submit" onclick="return calc_form()">

then:

```
function calc_form(first, second) {
        ...
        return false;
        ...
    }
```

Comment: The code is working fine even without return false;
Thanks for the explanation.